# Twilio Opt-in/Opt-out tracking

Tags: c#, twilio

How do I get all the phone numbers which have Opted-in or Opted-out via text to the short code? IS there any Twilio API which I can use? I need to import those numbers into SQL database.

Customers can text "Join" to short code and get opted-in and I need a list of all the phone numbers which are Opted-in and similarly customers can text STOP to opt-out. I am looking for a way to get all the numbers which have opted-in and opted-out. I am new to Twilio. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can track these events using your code. Twilio forwards all opt-in/opt-out to you backend application, the destination you have the Webhook configured for. You can do this with standard opt-outs or advanced opt-out. Currently, there is no API to view the Twilio maintained opt-in/opt-out list.

[Twilio support for opt-out keywords (SMS STOP filtering)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-)

[Customize opt-in and opt-out flows with Advanced Opt-Out](https://www.twilio.com/blog/introducing-advanced-opt-out)

Comment: Twilio does maintain a list because if you try to send a message to an opted-out number, it will fail. The good thing is that it does not appear as though you are charged for that attempt. One would think that you could query the list beforehand but maybe it is deliberate that you can't... no flooding of the system with queries. They may be deliberate in making us maintain our own list to eliminate the queries to their system.